# Add JavaScript to js file from external html page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({   
    url: "sub_template5_js.php?content_id="+content_id,  
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){  
        alert(data);
    }  
});
```

In above code, when i give alert **data** i get html with js script, i need to separate the javascript and append to the external .js file 
Pl. Help me

Thank you

Comment: _i need to separate the javascript and append to the external .js file_, It's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using script as selector should work..

```
$('script').text(); // use attribute selector to get a particular one .
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/7KJ5b/)

note: have to use loop , if incase you have more than one script tag.

this is just an example to get you started...

havn't tested with youe data part but you can try..

```
 data.find('script').text();
```